# How to add a webview in Collapsing Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, scroll

I added Empty activity in Android Studio.I want to convert it into Scrolling activity with web view.So I added below code into it.but its not working properly.how to solve it..Thank you...
I want to adview should parent in bottom also.

Here is my webview:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
```

Here is my other testing code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ABC">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/abcimage" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What you have in the complete code isn't WebView

Comment: I added other webview java class code.They are perfect.I want to above xml part only.